# Receiving an NLog error when running from our server, yet running locally is fine

Tags: c#, web-config, nlog

I'm experiencing an odd error involving NLog (ver2.1.0.0) in one of our older .net windows forms applications.

I made a change to the application & was able to run & test the change successfully, with no issues.  When we uploaded it to our QA Server (Windows Server  2008, I believe), we receive the following error:
**An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for nlog: Exception occurred when loading configuration from .exe.Config line 58**

Oddly, I can't seem to figure out why this is happening.  Here's my app.config code for nLog.  Line 58 is the first line, beginning with **< nlog xmlns...**

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      throwExceptions="true" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog.txt" internalLogLevel="Debug">
<variable name="applicationName" value="Load Import"/>
<targets>
  <target name="console" type="Console" layout="${date:format=HH\:mm\:ss} ${logger} ${level} ${message}${onexception:${newline}Exception\:${newline}${exception:format=tostring}}" />
  <target name="mail" xsi:type="Mail" smtpServer="relay.ourcompany.com" from="" to="" addNewLines="true" subject="ImportBill - ${level} ${onexception: Exception}" layout="Date: ${longdate}${newline}Level: ${uppercase:${level}}${newline}Logger: ${logger}${newline}Machine: ${machinename}${newline}Message: ${message}${onexception:${newline}Exception\:${newline}${exception:format=tostring}}${newline}" />
  <target name="database" xsi:type="Database" connectionStringName="Logging" keepConnection="true">
 <commandText>
    exec [nlog].[Message_Add]
    @LogDate = @logDate,
    @MachineName = @machineName,
    @ProcessName = @processName,
    @Version = @assemblyVersion,
    @Logger = @logger,
    @LogLevel = @logLevel,
    @Origin = @callSite,
    @Message = @message,
    @Exception = @exception,
    @StackTrace = @stackTrace,
    @WindowsIdentity = @windowsIdentity,
    @BaseDirectory = @baseDirectory,
    @AdditionalInfo = @additionalInfo,
    @RequestIdentifier = @requestIdentifier,
    @Log4JEvent = @log4jEvent
  </commandText>
  <parameter name="@logDate" layout="${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss.fff}" />
  <parameter name="@machineName" layout="${machinename}" />
  <parameter name="@ProcessName" layout="${processname}" />
  <parameter name="@assemblyVersion" layout="${assembly-version}" />
  <parameter name="@logger" layout="${logger}" />
  <parameter name="@logLevel" layout="${level}" />
  <parameter name="@callSite" layout="${callsite}" />
  <parameter name="@message" layout="${message}" />
  <parameter name="@exception" layout="${exception:format=tostring}" />
  <parameter name="@stackTrace" layout="${stacktrace}" />
  <parameter name="@windowsIdentity" layout="${windows-identity}" />
  <parameter name="@baseDirectory" layout="${basedir}" />
  <parameter name="@additionalInfo" layout="${mdc:item=AdditionalInfo}" />
  <parameter name="@requestIdentifier" layout="" />
  <parameter name="@log4jEvent" layout="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; ?&gt;&lt;data xmlns:log4j=&quot;http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/&quot; xmlns:nlog=&quot;http://nlog-project.org/&quot;&gt;${log4jxmlevent:includeSourceInfo=true:includeCallSite=true:includeMdc=true:includeNdc=true}&lt;/data&gt;" />
  </target>
</targets>
<rules>
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" maxLevel="Fatal" writeTo="database" />
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" maxLevel="Fatal" writeTo="mail" />
</rules>
```

Any idea what may be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: Where is line 58 in that app.config file?

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question to reflect line 58 is the first line of the code I provided.  Beginning with "< nlog xmlns..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I was able to at least figure out the underlying issue, so just figured I'd post it here in case anyone else comes across this problem.

I was experiencing a separate underlying error, which in my case was an invalid web service certificate.  The error was being caught by nlog but for reason which I still can't figure out, nlog was throwing an error as well.  Anyway, so I set the nlog "throwExceptions" in my config file equal to false & re-ran my application.  Doing this allowed me to discover the true underlying cause of my error, which in my case was "There is a problem with the certificate.  Connection to https://mywebservice.com/mywebservicename is forbidden"

Thanks

Comment: One should never use `throwExceptions="true"` in production. It is only intended for unit-testing and last-chance troubleshooting.